# Server requirements for a database with 150,000 records

Tags: php, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm developing an application based on Laravel framework. Although the project is pretty simple, it'll contain a lot of data. I've never in my whole life managed a server with that amount.

Perhaps for some of you 150,000 records is nothing, but for me it's a new thing.

It'll probably never go higher than 150,000.

So I have a few questions:

1. Is 150,000 too much or servers can handle that amount of data?
2. Should I worry about optimize everything or I am getting ahead of myself here?
3. What's your guess on server requirements?

Thank guys!

Comment: 150,000 records are nothing dont need to worry about the optimizations

Comment: Code it, get it working, then worry about optimization 150k rows is _small beer_

Comment: Remember that ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). This is even more true today than it was when Knuth wrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers in short:

1. 150,000 records are nothing.
2. Don't worry.
3. Every server can handle it.